# Part of jQuery code missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, colorbox

I am using colorbox which I have used many times for different clients, but it is not working this time and I can not figure out why. I am trying to open a video on YouTube, and then open up some inline HTML, I've copied the code from the examples just as I always do, and replaced what needs to be replaced. There are parts of the script that are missing when I look at the source code from the browser. The website is http://www.powerhousebowling.com. Maybe I'm missing something.

In my backend it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
    $(".open_colorbox").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_text"});
    });
</script>
```

But when I look at the source code in FF or IE it shows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".youtube").colorbox();
        $(".open_colorbox").colorbox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any chance this is a caching issue, e.g. did you ever upload the version with no parameters to your server?

Comment: I have cleared out all cache from browser to cms, I've always copied the code from the examples and replaced what has needed to be replaced. I've used colorbox for photos on about 8 other clients websites, this is the first time I have tried to use it for youtube and inline text, but I don't see why it would be too different. I have the colorbox folder with the js file, the css, and the images, and linked to them all correctly.

Comment: It's not cached, since I can verify from the link he provided that it's showing the "wrong" code. But the only possible explanation other than "you uploaded the wrong file" is that your web host is doing some inexplicable parsing. Occam's razor says "you uploaded the wrong file" is almost certainly the answer.

Comment: @Jeremy edit the file again and add something harmless like a "class" attribute on your `<script>` tag. Deploy that, and check your "view source" again. If the change is not there, then either you're being tormented by ghosts or else you're not uploading the file properly.

Comment: Ok I added a class to the <script> tag, and when I check the view source it is there.

Comment: @Pointy what do you think? Any advice?

Comment: The apparent behavior of your web server defies my understanding and is entirely new to my experience. It makes no sense at all. If faced with that myself, I *might* try some random experiments to see if I could figure out what's triggering the weirdness, with the emphasis on **random** - spacing/indentation/line-break changes, quoting property names, putting the script in a different part of the file, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I will have to try that, I have no idea what is going on, I've never had this problem with colorbox.

Comment: *sigh* still nothing, I have no idea what's going on, other scripts as you can see in the source code are fine. I even took everything color box out, deleted off the server and did everything like new again. Even re-downloaded the colorbox files lol.

Comment: try adding <![CDATA[ ]]> in your script , what backend you are using ?

Comment: @Jeremy: What happens if you add this line to your code - `alert({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344}.iframe)`. Does view source give you the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was happening about a week ago, sorry for the delay in answering, I was out of the office. The CMS that we use, ExpressionEngine, was thinking anything between the curly brackets were tags for itself, I took the script outside the CMS and pointed to it, works fine! Hope this helps anyone else!

Comment: well that's exactly what Naoise Golden said, why not accept his answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the code you are mentioning is inputed in some kind of backend, the software or the server is probably striping the code for security reason. See what happens if you remove de curly brackets and if the code appears then try finding how to insert them following the software's rules (`{literal}{/literal}` if it is a Smarty template)